# Oracle Apex Checkbox when read only showing session violation error

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a page item which is a checkbox : P1_EMPID

It was editable previously but now i have requirement to add another button on click of which this would be checked.

I set P1_EMP_ID property-> Readonly-> Always

```
Maintain Session State-> Always
Session state protection unrestricted.
```

On the button-> I have set value dynamic action which sets P1_EMPID TO Y to check the checkbox. When i click button assignment happens, But when i proceed using update button in page it throws following erro:

Session state protection violation: This may be caused by protected page item.

But value protected for the item is set to No.

What could be the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is expected behaviour. “Read Only” does not only control how an item is displayed; it also protects the item against changes. The server makes sure that the item is indeed “Read Only”, and that the browser is not able to change the item value on the server. The solution to not use the "Read Only" attribute but use the css class "apex_disabled"

[image]